# Separating Zip Codes

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

I have some data with zip codes separated by a comma. I know I can separate the values by "Text to Columns", however, I am having an issue with the zip codes that start with zero.

For example, this is how my data looks

[image]

And then when I use text to columns it comes out like this

[image]

I know I can change the output to come as text, which can fix it when its a few zip codes

[image]

But I have some data points with hundreds of zip codes like that. I was wondering if anyone knew of a better method to separate these values, but maintain the 5 digits of the zip code.

Thanks

Comment: In the last step of the text to columns set the columns as text.

Comment: That's feasible when I have only a couple of zip codes, but when I have hundreds, its much tougher to set all those columns to text

Comment: try the answer provided by @Ash. Firstly use `text to columns` to separate the codes, and then highlight all the codes and apply the custom formatting of `00000` to always show a 5-digit number. You could've searched this solution online I think...

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if all you want is to "see" the zip code with Leading zeroes. If that is what you are trying to do, simply apply a format to your result cells - that will display any 4 digit number, with leading 0s. 
You have to set a custom formatting to display the leading zeroes by entering 5 0s in the number format Type box. See the custom format in picture below;
[Custom Excel Formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2VHl.png)

Comment: A good answer. I would suggest you to put down the exact custom formatting code which is `00000` in this case, and maybe share a screenshot of the before `6033` and after `06033` result to make your answer clearer.

Answer (score 0):

So, this works using left() mid() & right with find() - quick and dirty though, I will let you exercise your talents to deal with 4 codes...

[image]